# PHP 5.4 Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed - way to ignore?

Tags: php

I have to work with some legacy PHP 4 code. I have PHP 5.4 installed on my machine and getting this nasty error:

```
"Fatal error: Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed in ..."
```

I already found a solution/fix, but it requires changes in existing code.
My questions is - is there a way to **IGNORE** this error? I don't want to fix it (as it requires a LOT of code changes), but ignore and do my work. I am looking for some kind of "config" change in PHP/Apache, so I do not need to mess with legacy code.

Yes, yes... I know that is not a good practice, but unfortunately that is what I need right now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I catch a PHP Fatal Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277224/how-do-i-catch-a-php-fatal-error)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A fatal error cannot be stopped (this is why they are called fatal) - not even by stuff like `set_error_handler`.

You **will** have to change your code.

But fixing it should not be a huge problem, because the error is caused by `&` in function calls:

```
function test($param) { }
test(&$test);      // fatal error

function test(&$param) { }
test($test);       // no error
```

[Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php):

- As of PHP 5.3.0, you will get a warning saying that "call-time pass-by-reference" is deprecated when you use & in foo(&$a);.
- And as of PHP 5.4.0, call-time pass-by-reference was removed, so using it will raise a fatal error.

So to make a (very) nasty workaround, you could install PHP 5.3.0 :(

Comment: Too bad it can't be done by some kind of config change. Anyway, thanks for making it clear! I guess I would have to downgrade to 5.3, as removing pass-by-reference caused existing code to not work properly.